# R dplyr nested dummy coding

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable

I need to recode a data set of test responses for use in another application (a program called BLIMP that imputes missing values). Specifically, I need to represent the test items and subscale assignments with dummy codes.

Here I create a data frame that holds the responses to a 10-item test for two persons in a nested format. These data are a simplified version of the actual input table.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  person = rep(101:102, each = 10),
  item = as.factor(rep(1:10, 2)),
  response = sample(1:4, 20, replace = T),
  scale = as.factor(rep(rep(1:2, each = 5), 2))
) %>% mutate(
  scale_last = case_when(
    as.integer(scale) != lead(as.integer(scale)) | is.na(lead(as.integer(scale))) ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  )
)
```

The columns of `df` contain:

- `person`: ID numbers for the persons (10 rows for each person)
- `item`: test items 1-10 for each person. Note how the items are nested within each person.
- `response`: score for each item
- `scale`: the test has two subscales. Items 1-5 are assigned to subscale 1, and items 6-10 are assigned to subscale 2.
- `scale_last`: a code of `1` in this column indicates that the item is the last item in its assigned sub scale. This characteristic becomes important below.

I then create dummy codes for the items using the `recipes` package.

```
library(recipes)
dum <- df %>% 
  recipe(~ .) %>% 
  step_dummy(item, one_hot = T) %>% 
  prep(training = df) %>%
  bake(new_data = df)
print(dum, width = Inf)

#   person response scale scale_last item_X1 item_X2 item_X3 item_X4 item_X5 item_X6 item_X7
#    <int>    <int> <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1    101        2 1             NA       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
# 2    101        3 1             NA       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
# 3    101        3 1             NA       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
# 4    101        1 1             NA       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
# 5    101        1 1              1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
# 6    101        1 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
# 7    101        3 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
# 8    101        4 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# 9    101        2 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#10    101        4 2              1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#11    102        2 1             NA       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
#12    102        1 1             NA       0       1       0       0       0       0       0
#13    102        2 1             NA       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
#14    102        3 1             NA       0       0       0       1       0       0       0
#15    102        2 1              1       0       0       0       0       1       0       0
#16    102        1 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
#17    102        4 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
#18    102        2 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#19    102        4 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#20    102        3 2              1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#   item_X8 item_X9 item_X10
#     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1       0       0        0
# 2       0       0        0
# 3       0       0        0
# 4       0       0        0
# 5       0       0        0
# 6       0       0        0
# 7       0       0        0
# 8       1       0        0
# 9       0       1        0
#10       0       0        1
#11       0       0        0
#12       0       0        0
#13       0       0        0
#14       0       0        0
#15       0       0        0
#16       0       0        0
#17       0       0        0
#18       1       0        0
#19       0       1        0
#20       0       0        1
```

The output shows the item dummy codes represented in the columns with the `item_` prefix. For downstream processing, I need a further level of recoding. Within each subscale, the items must be dummy-coded relative to the last item of the subscale. Here’s where the `scale_last` variable comes into play; this variable identifies the rows in the output that need to be recoded.

For example, the first of these rows is row 5, the row for the last item (item 5) in subscale 1 for person 101. In this row the value of column `item_X5` needs to be recoded from `1` to `0`.  In the next row to be recoded (row 10), it is the value of `item_X10` that needs to be recoded from `1` to `0`. And so on.

I’m struggling for the right combination of `dplyr` verbs to accomplish this. What’s tripping me up is the need to isolate specific cells within specific rows to be recoded.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` and `replace` values from `"item"` columns to 0 where `scale_last == 1`

```
library(dplyr)

dum %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("item")), ~replace(., scale_last == 1, 0))

# A tibble: 20 x 14
#   person response scale scale_last item_X1 item_X2 item_X3 item_X4 item_X5
#    <int>    <int> <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1    101        2 1             NA       1       0       0       0       0
# 2    101        3 1             NA       0       1       0       0       0
# 3    101        1 1             NA       0       0       1       0       0
# 4    101        1 1             NA       0       0       0       1       0
# 5    101        3 1              1       0       0       0       0       0
# 6    101        4 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
# 7    101        4 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
# 8    101        3 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
# 9    101        2 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
#10    101        4 2              1       0       0       0       0       0
#11    102        2 1             NA       1       0       0       0       0
#12    102        1 1             NA       0       1       0       0       0
#13    102        4 1             NA       0       0       1       0       0
#14    102        4 1             NA       0       0       0       1       0
#15    102        4 1              1       0       0       0       0       0
#16    102        3 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
#17    102        4 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
#18    102        1 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
#19    102        4 2             NA       0       0       0       0       0
#20    102        4 2              1       0       0       0       0       0
# … with 5 more variables: item_X6 <dbl>, item_X7 <dbl>, item_X8 <dbl>,
#   item_X9 <dbl>, item_X10 <dbl>
```

---

In base R, we can use `lapply`

```
cols <- grep("^item", names(dum))
dum[cols] <- lapply(dum[cols], function(x) replace(x, dum$scale_last == 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, I was stuck on `mutate_if` and couldn't make it work.